# c# графики строятся не с начальной точки

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Строю 2 графика на одном поле chart'а:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Набор данных для серии "Тест" по Х начинается со значения 28, а для серии "Эксплуатация" - с 20. На графике они начинаются с одного значения, хотя должны совпадать у них только конечные точки, т.к. последние значения для обоих наборов - 90.

Строю их вот таким образом:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(Data.Tests.Tables["TestTable"].Select(), "TTest", "LTest", null);
chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBind(Data.WorkTest.Select(), "T", "L", null);
```

*Источники данных - таблица DataTable из DataSet и просто отдельная DataTable для 1 и 2 серии соответственно

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы отображались они корректно?

**UPD**

Неполные наборы данных:

```
Эксплуатация            Тест
   X    Y              X    Y
19.06   257         27.9    252 
20.00   270         29.0    261
21.00   285         30.0    271
22.00   301         31.0    281
23.00   316         32.0    292
24.00   332         33.0    303
...     ...         ...     ...
87.00   2931        87.0    1551
88.00   3007        88.0    1592
89.00   3086        89.0    1631
90.00   3166        90.0    1672
```

Comment: @aepot chart - элемент управления windows forms, который представляет из себя  поле для построения графиков и диаграмм

Comment: Думаю что на вопрос заданны в такой форме вряд ли кто поможет. Здесь было бы коректно прикрепить и сами наборы данных.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26867376/12888024